# Making a python script executable in python 2.7

Tags: python, executable

We are trying to make our python script execute itself as a .exe file, without having python installed. Like if we give our program to someone else, they wouldn't need to install python to open it.

It is a text-based game like zork, so we need a gui, like cmd, to run it.

We have tried using py2exe, and pyinstaller, but none of them made any sense, and don't work with 2.7.3 for some reason.

Any help?

Comment: Also, could you make a python script open cmd, with the path to the file, so that you can run it from there? With python installed of course. I see that as much easier than making an executable anyways. Just trying to look for something else than having to type the whole C:\python27\python.exe game.py shebang.

Comment: Why don't py2exe and pyinstaller make sense?

Comment: @poplitea When we try installing it, it either: Doesn't find python 2.7, or: doesn't work installing at all.

Comment: They both should work with python 2.7. I would suggest sticking with pyinstaller.

Comment: @jdi We fixed it with cx_freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can always try http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net, works with all versions of python including 3.3.

Comment: Tried to find a good tutorial on how to use that software. We have it now, but we can't find out how to use it. We can't even find an exe file in there...

Comment: It should download as a MSI and can auto-install. Documentation is here: http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html. Can you describe your issue in more detail?

Comment: Ok, we found everything, the compiler and all. We get the error "Cannot get zipimporter instance"

Comment: Can you expand on this some?

Comment: we fixed it! We were just using the wrong syntax when we were exporting the file xD

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have pip installed which you should after installing Python inside folder *Scripts*.
Install PyInstaller using pip, type in the command prompt the following.

- pip install pyinstaller

After you install PyInstaller locate where your pyinstaller files are (*they should be where your pip files are inside the Scripts folder*) and go to the command prompt and type the following.

- c:\python27\Scripts>**pyinstaller --onefile c:\yourscript.py**

The above command will create a folder called “dist” inside the *Scripts* folder, this will contain your single executable file “yourscript.exe”.

Comment: the easiest solution so far :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this wiki on deploying Python applications:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/deployment

In addition to what's already been mentioned, it has links to Movable Python, Python-Packager, and others.

Comment: Those deployments are either for mac, linux or older versions of python. We're using windows 7 32-bit and python 2.7 :/

Answer (score -4):

[Download this, should work for python 2.7.3](http://tenet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/py2exe/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe)